# What are the natural ways to increase the blood, and the amniotic acids flow to the uterus during pregnancy?

Tags: health, pregnancy

That's the question.

What are the natural ways to increase the blood, and the amniotic acids flow to the uterus during pregnancy?

What should be the duration and intensity of the exercises (if any)?

Comment: unrelated, but for maximum blood flow, make sure to drink lots of water.

Comment: @Charles thanks for the help. I have now started drinking 4 litres of water and I am feeling a "visible" difference in my activeness.

Answer (score 5):

As a woman who has given birth to three premature babies and suffered miscarriage. My pregnancies were the most precious thing to ever happen to me.

Having said this: ***Most women do NOT experience these combined problems***.

However, the no one is qualified here, not even an obstetrician, to advise you on exercise or blood-flow to the uterus or amniotic acids.

I have studied Medical Science and this combined with the multiple complications of my pregnancies, I cannot emphasize enough, to anyone who may be pregnant and read this. Do NOT take any online advice from strangers.

In my instance, I even had a friend, who was an experienced midwife tell me that exercise cannot cause miscarriage, I was later put on total bed-rest for months to help maintain the pregnancy. It is commonly known that walking around helps to "bring on labor" in women who are overdue, or wanting to speed up labor.

Having said this, for most women, exercising in pregnancy is fine and healthy. I have no idea if you fall into this category. Pregnancy is not the time to increase exercise, or embark on new exercise, it's a time to gradually reduce exercise intensity. To have a gentler regime. The ligaments throughout the body soften, from the massive amounts of progesterone in a pregnant woman's body. This is what aids in softening the birth canal and enabling it to stretch around a babies head. This also allows the joins in the pelvic girdle to soften, so it can stretch a little.

In the third trimester of pregnancy a woman should not lie on her back for too long, as the weight of the baby and uterus puts pressure on blood vessels. This also needs to be considered.

As for squats, I ruptured my membranes squatting in my first pregnancy.

As for increasing blood flow, and a healthy uterine environment, I recommend a healthy diet. Adequate iron, calcium and vitamin c intake. Vitamin c helps the uptake of iron, which is needed for healthy blood supply. Calcium is needed for muscle to function properly, and the demands during pregnancy increase, as the baby is forming bones, muscles etc. Low calcium levels can lead to cramps. I recommend getting such intake through diet, not tablets.

Eating a balance diet with a view to increasing foods with low GI, combined with gentle exercise (if advised by the professional caring for you in your pregnancy) and keeping weight gain  in check (a non-pregnant BMI in the "healthy range"); helps reduce the risk of gestational diabetes. Gestational diabetes can cause an overproduction of amniotic fluid, which in turn can lead to premature labor from ruptured membranes. It also affects the blood flow to the baby, increasinging glucose levels.

Cutting back on excessive salt intake, also aides in keeping blood pressure down. As elevated blood pressure, increases the risk of pre-eclampsia, which causes compromised blood flow and decreased growth rate of the unborn child.

There are herbal teas that I have seen recommended (and I will not name any herb or drug here) by women, that, actually assists in causing contractions of the uterus.

Having said everything, the key is, it all needs to be moderated and supervised. Over doing any of the above suggestions can also lead to health problems.

I hope this helps someone. I wish you luck with your baby.

If you require links to validate my claims, please ask.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out,i removed my answer :) feel free to comment on answers so that i could improve too thanks

Comment: @Vignesh4303 ty for being so good about it.. pregnancy is something we have to be very careful about giving advice. I am sure you have much to contribute. I have posted many downvoted answers in my time on [se].. we can't be right all the time :)